# error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm learning Angular Material and I'm getting this error when importing { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button".

From what I read in other answers, it looks like package compatibility issues but I couldn't fix it.

Here's the full error

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(29,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(30,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(128,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(129,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(134,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/focus-trap/focus-trap.d.ts(135,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/key-manager/list-key-manager.d.ts(96,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/key-manager/list-key-manager.d.ts(98,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/live-announcer/live-announcer.d.ts(69,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/a11y/live-announcer/live-announcer.d.ts(70,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts(62,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts(63,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts(66,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
    node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/observe-content.d.ts(67,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
```

Here's my package.json

```
"name": "football",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.21",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.21",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

According to your package.json, you're using Angular 8.3, but you've imported angular/cdk v9. You can downgrade your angular/cdk version or you can upgrade your Angular version to v9 by running:

`ng update @angular/core @angular/cli`

That will update your local angular version to 9. Then, just to sync material, run:
`ng update @angular/material`

Comment: Thanks, I encountered this issue when I installed angular flex which automatically installed the latest version (version 9 in my case) but I was working with angular 8. Correcting the version solved the issue

Comment: @Kyler johnson how can i downgred angular/cdk

Comment: @mdkamrul you can downgrade by running `npm i @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8 @angular/material@8`, assuming you were on version 8. Sometimes your package.json and package-lock.json will get out of sync and your project will use what's inside of the package-lock.json file. So now, run `npm i` to sync them up. If you still run into problems after that, run `npm ci` to do a completely clean install of your dependencies

Comment: I had to use `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --force`, because the packages are itself incompatible und you can't switch otherwise.

Answer (score 74):

Adding `skipLibCheck: true` in `compilerOptions` inside `tsconfig.json` file fixed my issue.

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "skipLibCheck": true,
},
```

Comment: But, will skipping lib check not cause other problems in future?

Comment: thanks @R15 it worked for me and I am using angular 8

Comment: You absolute legend. This works a treat. I was worried about using the other fix of updating typescript, in case, my version of Angular is incompatible...

Comment: It works like hell... Thanks a lot for saving my time

Answer (score 3):

These issue arise generally  due to mismatch between **@ngx-translate/core**    version and **Angular** .Before installing check compatible version of corresponding ngx_trnalsate/Core, @ngx-translate/http-loader and Angular at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core

Eg: For Angular 6.X versions,

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core@10 @ngx-translate/http-loader@3 rxjs --save
```

Like as above, follow below command and rest of code part is common for all versions(Note: Version can obtain from( https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core)

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core@version @ngx-translate/http-loader@version rxjs --save
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i @ionic/storage@2.2.0
```

this is install to degrade your storage package

Comment: After days of updating all items to newest parts, system stay incompatible for firestore and this was the solution to stay on old version on all dependent modules and downdate storage to 2.2.

Comment: Yes , that is correct @Nasenbaer

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar issue, had to downgrade my package version with respect to the version of my angular project version

Answer (score 0):

First please check in `module.ts` file that in `@NgModule` all properties are only one time.
If any of are more than one time then also this error come.
Because I had also occur this error but in `module.ts` file `entryComponents` property were two time that's why I was getting this error.
I resolved this error by removing one time `entryComponents` from `@NgModule`.
So, I recommend that first you check it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but didn't have a version conflict in my package.json.

My package-lock.json was somehow out of sync with package json though. Deleting and regenerating it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by following steps:

Check the angular version: Using command: ng version My angular version is: Angular CLI: 7.3.10

After that I have support version of ngx bootstrap from the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap

In package.json file update the version: "bootstrap": "^4.5.3", "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.2.2",

Now after updating package.json, use the command npm update

After this use command ng serve and my error got resolved